# How do I subtract time from a running countdown timer?

Tags: vb.net, timer

Basically, I have a timer that counts down from 3 minutes while the user takes a test. If the user skips a question, I want to incur a 15-second penalty. So they then have 15 seconds less time to finish. Example: The Timer is at 2:35. The user hits skip, and the timer goes down to 2:20, and continues on. Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private TargetDT As DateTime
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.AcceptButton = btnprocess
    End Sub
    Private Sub tmrCountdown_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrCountdown.Tick
        Dim ts As TimeSpan = TargetDT.Subtract(DateTime.Now)
        If ts.TotalMilliseconds > 0 Then
            lbltimer.Text = ts.ToString("mm\:ss")
        Else
            lbltimer.Text = "00:00"
            tmrCountdown.Stop()
            MessageBox.Show("Done")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnskip_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnskip.Click
        ' This is where I want to subtract 15 seconds
        Dim ts As TimeSpan = TargetDT.Subtract(DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)))
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnbegin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnbegin.Click
        tmrCountdown.Interval = 1
        TargetDT = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2.5))
        tmrCountdown.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `TargetDT` value, so on the next `Tick` event the display will be updated.

I also changed your code to use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now` so clever users can't change the timezone to gain additional time (as changing the timezone does not require administrative/elevated permissions).

You also don't need to specify a super-high timer frequency (you had it set to update every milisecond). This is excessive. I set it to 4Hz so the on-screen display won't lag too much.

```
Private Sub btnskip_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnskip.Click

    Me.TargetDT = Me.TargetDT.Subtract( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 15 ) )

End Sub

Private Sub tmrCountdown_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrCountdown.Tick

    Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow

    If now > Me.TargetDT Then

        Me.lbltimer.Text = "00:00"
        Me.tmrCountdown.Stop()
        MessageBox.Show("Done")

    Else

        Dim diff As TimeSpan = Me.TargetDT - now
        Me.lbltimer.Text = diff.ToString("mm\:ss")

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnbegin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnbegin.Click

    Me.tmrCountdown.Interval = 250 ' no need to update more than 4 times a second
    Me.TargetDT = DateTime.UtcNow.Add( TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2.5) )

    Me.tmrCountdown.Start()
End Sub
```